# Copy data from cells in sheet to next available row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a POS system for a startup business.

I need to copy fixed cells from the invoice and paste them into a table that archives the sales data. The cells aren't in the same row or column.

The cells to be copied are as follows (From "SalesSheet"):
"E4", "E5", "C5", "C6", "F23", "F24", "F26"

These need to be pasted in that order into the next free row in the "SalesArchive" Sheet.

I searched but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim sSrc()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsTgt As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    sSrc = Array("E4", "E5", "C5", "C6", "F23", "F24", "F26")

    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Invoice")
    Set wsTgt = Worksheets("SalesArchive")
    Set c = wsTgt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    For i = LBound(sSrc) To UBound(sSrc)
        c.Offset(1, i).Value = wsSrc.Range(sSrc(i)).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: AAAAAA DUDE!!!!!!! or Dudet! You are amazing! This is exactly what i needed! 

Thank you so so much